# Widget ImageButton listener not allways called

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a simple Widget (Android 2.1) containing just a LinearLayout, itself containing an ImageButton.
The ImageButton has a on-click listener.
The problem is: If I put several of this same widget on my home screen, some are working (listener called when button pressed), and some are not! I cannot see any pattern in which are working and which are not.

Here is the widget layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:src="@drawable/widget_running"
    android:background="@null">
</ImageButton>
```

And here is the widget provider code:

```
public class GPAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
private String mTag = getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    Log.e(mTag, "onUpdate ");

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Log.e(mTag, "widget onUpdate one loop");
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Create an Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GPService.class).setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_TOGGLE_PAUSE);
        intent.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pauseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.gp_appwidget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageButton01, pauseIntent);

        // widget update
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: An update: It seems that if I restart the phone or the app then all widgets are working... But if I add new widgets, most of the time they won't work until I restart the phone or restart the app...

Comment: I'm also experiencing this, once I add the homescreen widget it doesn't attach the listeners to the buttons immediately. I have to run the service / start the app via home icons to trigger the update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Don't forget to set a different "requestCode" when you call "getService" :

```
public static PendingIntent getService (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

And make sure your "appWidgetId" is different for each widget.